# Resample timestamps hourly/daily and combine values of other corresponding rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Looking to resample timeframe hourly/ daily/ weekly/ monthly/ yearly and combine the values from the corresponding rows

Dataframe (26 columns)

```
_id reqId statusCode requestUrl .... gatewayReqInTime ... payload
0    R1    401          /a             1560930471866      {"a":"b"}
1    R2    206          /b             1560935448236      {"c":"d"}
2    R3    200          /c             1560940623889      {"e":"f"}
3    R4    200          /d             1575365628749      {"g":"h"} 
4    R5    201          /e             1560935447889      {"i":"j"}
```

Required output

```
gatewayReqInTime_Date count _id     reqId      statusCode   requestUrl ....... payload
2019-06-19 13:00:00    1    [0]      [R1]      [401]        ["/a"]                .
2019-06-19 14:00:00    2    [1,4]    [R2, R5]  [206, 201]   ["/b", "/e"]          .
2019-06-19 16:00:00    1    [2]      [R3]      [200]        ["/c"]                .
2019-12-03 15:00:00    1    [3]      [R4]      [200]        ["/d"]                .
```

I could convert timestamps into datetime, resample and get the count (first 2 columns of the output)

However, I'm facing trouble in combining the values. Tried groupby, agg etc..

```
df['gateWayReqinTime_Date'] = df['gateWayReqinTime'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df2 = (df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gateWayReqinTime_Date', freq='H'))
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='Count'))
df2
```

PS : Its a Javascript developer's first week in Python. Please suggest ways considering the column labels to be dynamic or unspecific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following approach is close to what you want:

```
df = df.astype(str)
df['gateWayReqInTime_Date'] = df['gateWayReqInTime'].apply(lambda d: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)/1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
df.drop('gateWayReqInTime', inplace=True, axis=1)
df['gateWayReqInTime_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['gateWayReqInTime_Date'])
df2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gateWayReqInTime_Date', freq='H')).agg(', '.join)
df2['count'] = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='gateWayReqInTime_Date', freq='H'))['_id'].agg('count')

print(df2.head())

                        _id   reqId statusCode requestUrl                 payload  count
gateWayReqInTime_Date                                       
2019-06-19 12:00:00       0      R1        401         /a               {'a': 'b'}      1
2019-06-19 13:00:00    4, 1  R5, R2   201, 206     /e, /b   {'i': 'j'}, {'c': 'd'}      2
2019-06-19 14:00:00                                                                     0
2019-06-19 15:00:00       2      R3        200         /c               {'e': 'f'}      1
2019-06-19 16:00:00                                                                     0
```